# Should my rspec tests making db connections?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I find it bad practise that my rspec tests are making db calls.

(I have some tests that test for page titles on views, and my application_controller hits the db to fetch objects used in the layout)

How can I mock them out? Or is this normal?  Seems a test that hits the db is getting into a integration test...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert on this and still struggle with what to mock and what not. I would say that if possible, try to mock it, because it's not about the database. Still, when you're doing a lot with the object in the view, it will become cumbersome to mock it all and creating a record is much easier. At a cost of slow specs though.

Might creating a new object, without storing it in the database, be an option too?